# How do I reinitialize a frame before I raise it in tkinter?

Tags: python, class, tkinter, frame

I have a problem regarding updating frames in tkinter. When I am in the `Search` frame, I update a file with some information, and then switch frames to the `ShowSearch` class. However, when the mainloop runs for the first time, it runs and initializes all the classes, so that my `ShowSearch` frame will display information in the file from the previous run of the program. My question is if there is a way for me to send data to the file `storeSearch.txt`, and then when I have called `controller.show_frame(ShowSearch)`, my `ShowSearch` class will reinitialize and retrieve the data from the file `storeSearch.txt` and then display it. I only need help with reinitializing/updating the class since I already have written the code that retrieves the data from the file and displays it in my `ShowSearch` class.

```
import tkinter as tk
import Projekt_KTH_GUI as PK
import functools

class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Homescreen, Menuscreen, Create, ShowUpcoming, ShowAll, OpenList, Search, Edit, ShowSearch):

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame(Homescreen)

    def show_frame(self, container):

        frame = self.frames[container]
        frame.tkraise()
```

```
class Search(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Label(self, text = "Sök efter packningslista", font = ("Times new Roman", 30)).place(x = 110, y = 0)

        self.objectList = PK.main()
        self.search = tk.StringVar()

        tk.Label(self, text = "Var god mata in ditt sökord:").place(x = 150, y = 100)
        search  = tk.Entry(self, textvariable = self.search, width = 40).place(x = 60, y = 120)
        search_button = tk.Button(self, text = "Enter", command = self.getList).place(x = 430, y = 122.5)
        menuButton = tk.Button(self, text = "Meny", command = lambda: self.controller.show_frame(Menuscreen)).place(x = 100, y = 300)

    def getList(self):

        searchWord = self.search.get()
        objectList = self.objectList

        objectList = PK.search(objectList, searchWord)

        PK.filesUpdate(objectList, "storeSearch.txt")

        return self.controller.show_frame(ShowSearch)
```

I tried to use the methods `.update()` and `.destroy()`, one line before i execute `frame.tkraise()`, but  the `.update()` method doesn't do anything and when I use the `.destroy()` method, I get an error saying `_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!frame.!showsearch"`.

Comment: You need to make a minimal reproducible example. Strip out everything that doesn't matter and give us some tiny little code that reproduces your problem. I can't even run what you posted. Staring at your code til I notice the problem is far too inefficient.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy Will do! Sorry for the troubles.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy I did so now, if you have time to take a look at it I would be greatful!

Comment: When you can copy/paste your question code in an editor, hit the go button, and get the same error as you, then you've created a minimal reproducible example. Whatever you changed is not enough. You should have a `tk` root, 1 frame and a problem. Nothing else. I should be able to just copy it, run it and get the same error as you. Search, Homescreen, all that can go. Even container, what is that doing? You could just put it all on the root.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74567783/how-do-i-reinitialize-a-frame-in-tkinter, I'm sorry, this is my changed question and code. I will remove this question. Maybe it's still not enough information, I'm sorry I am new to stack overflow.