# How do I reinitialize a frame in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, frames

I have a program that deals a lot with creating objects from data in files with the ability to edit the objects and then save them in the same file. I am implementing a GUI, and I am using tkinter to do it. The problem I am facing is the problem of frames not updating when I jump back and forth between frames, since the constructor method only runs once when the program begins, and which is where I produce most of the widgets on the screen. Below is an example of what I would like to accomplish:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Homescreen, Menuscreen):

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame(Homescreen)

    def show_frame(self, container):

        frame = self.frames[container]
        frame.tkraise()

class Homescreen(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
            text = f.readline()
        
        tk.Label(self, text = text).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text = "next page", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(Menuscreen)).pack()
        

class Menuscreen(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        
        self.entry = tk.StringVar()

        tk.Entry(self, textvariable = self.entry).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text = "back to page", command = self.writeToFile).pack()

        
    def writeToFile(self):

        with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
            f.writelines(self.entry.get())
        
        self.controller.show_frame(Homescreen)


app = App()
app.geometry("500x400")
app.mainloop()
```

If I have a textfile with just a simple word, in `Homescreen` i print it out on the screen. Then I move to the second frame, `Menuscreen`, where I allow the user to enter another word, and then I store the word in the same textfile. Then the program takes us back to the `Homescreen`, but the problem is that the printed out word, will still be the first word and not the updated word in the textfile.

I tried to use the methods `.update()` and `.destroy()`, one line before i execute `frame.tkraise()`, but the `.update()` method doesn't do anything and when I use the `.destroy()` method, I get an error saying `_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name`

Comment: You have ask another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74564648/how-do-i-reinitialize-a-frame-before-i-raise-it-in-tkinter).  What is the difference between them? You should add extra information in the last question instead of raising new question.

Comment: @acw1668 I posted that comment and someone said that it was to much information to understand what my problem is, so I made a new much simpler program so that it could be clear what I wanted to accomplish, but apparently it wasn't enough, so I will just try to find some other wat to solve my problem since I don't understand how stackoverflow works...

Comment: @MoniqueAshenaz ~ You could read the criteria on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [what to do when someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the "printed out word" to change because the constructor for `Homescreen` is only run once. You need another method that changes the entry when you raise the `Frame`. The changes are commented below. There are only 4.

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Homescreen, Menuscreen):

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame(Homescreen)

    def show_frame(self, container):
        frame = self.frames[container]

        #update the label
        if container is Homescreen: frame.update_label()

        frame.tkraise()


class Homescreen(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            
        #keep a reference to the label so it can be modified
        self.label = tk.Label(self)
        self.label.pack()
        
        tk.Button(self, text = "next page", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(Menuscreen)).pack()
        
        self.update_label()
        
    #update the label
    def update_label(self):
        with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
            self.label['text'] = f.read()
        
        
class Menuscreen(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        
        self.entry = tk.StringVar()

        tk.Entry(self, textvariable = self.entry).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text = "back to page", command = self.writeToFile).pack()
        
    def writeToFile(self):
        with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(self.entry.get())
           
        #go back to homescreen 
        self.controller.show_frame(Homescreen)


app = App()
app.geometry("500x400")
app.mainloop()
```

If you'd like to make your script a little easier to work with, I refactored it below, and left comments.

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        
        #you do not need `container`
        #using root as the master makes it a more natural controller
        #you were using it more like a proxy        

        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        #you created a convention with your class names of using "screen"
        #use some kind of "screen" for everything that contains or directly relates to them
        self.screens = {}

        #don't "juggle"
        #create a var, and use it
        for screen in (Menuscreen, Homescreen):
            self.screens[screen] = screen(self)
            self.screens[screen].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    #renamed to reflect that it relates to your screens
    def show_screen(self, screen):
        target = self.screens[screen]
        
        if screen is Homescreen: target.update_label()
        
        target.tkraise()


class Homescreen(tk.Frame):
    #whatever you put in master becomes the `self.master` of this widget
    #ie.. we are keeping the names the same
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
            
        self.label = tk.Label(self)
        self.label.pack()
        
        #this line illustrates how the root is the controller
        tk.Button(self, text="next page", command=lambda: master.show_screen(Menuscreen)).pack()
        
        #init the label text
        self.update_label()
        
    def update_label(self):
        with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
            self.label['text'] = f.read()
        
        
class Menuscreen(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        
        self.entry = tk.StringVar()

        tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.entry).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="back to page", command=self.writeToFile).pack()
        
    def writeToFile(self):
        with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(self.entry.get())
        
        #illustrates again how the root is the controller        
        self.master.show_screen(Homescreen)


#this is good practice
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.geometry("500x400")
    app.mainloop()
```